# How to resolve "ReferenceError: accounts is not defined at Suite"

Tags: solidity, truffle

When I run trufflle test, I get the following error message.

> ReferenceError: accounts is not defined at Suite.
> (/Users/tsuru/fundraiser/test/fundraiser_test.js:59:28)

The relevant code is here.

https://github.com/okahijiki/fundraiser

Please let us know how to deal with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

im looking at this repo file
https://github.com/okahijiki/fundraiser/blob/main/test/fundraiser_test.js

And looks like is a visibility problem, you are closing the `contract` function on line `22` so all the code below can`t see the variable accounts.

If you want to access to the `accounts` close it on line `80` instead the `22`

Short example :

```
contract("Fundraiser", accounts => {

 beforeEach(async () => {
  // Your code
 })
 describe("initialization", () => {
  // Your code , now you can acces to accounts varaible 
 })
})
```

Comment: I m able to clear the problem.Thank you :）